# how do i make it possible for a window with buttons program to run?

Tags: java

i have coded this program on an Eclipse development environment and i get only one error that says.

"Error: Could not find or load main class incremental"

please help.

this is prototype for making a simple incremental game.

```
package pkIncremental;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Incremental extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Incremental();
    }
    private JLabel lblHead1;
    private JLabel lblMessage;
    private JButton btnQuit;
    private JButton btnObtainMess;
    private JButton btnVis;
    private JButton btnNotVis;

    public Incremental()
    {
        this.setSize(600,500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Incremtial game!");
        this.setLayout(null);
        Font f = new Font("JSL Ancient", Font.ITALIC,24);
        final String M = "The points are bellow";

        lblHead1 = new JLabel (M);
        lblHead1.setBounds(150, 50, 200, 50);
        lblHead1.setFont(f);
        this.add(lblHead1);

        lblMessage = new JLabel("X");
        lblMessage.setOpaque(true);
        lblMessage.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        lblMessage.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 50);
        lblMessage.setFont(f);
        lblMessage.setForeground(Color.RED);
        this.add(lblMessage);

        btnObtainMess = new JButton("Click to get points.");
        btnObtainMess.setBounds(100, 150, 300, 50);
        btnObtainMess.setFont(f);
        btnObtainMess.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(btnObtainMess);

        btnNotVis = new JButton("not VIsible");
        btnNotVis.setBounds(100, 250, 150, 50);
        btnNotVis.setFont(f);
        btnNotVis.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(btnNotVis);

        btnVis = new JButton("Visible");
        btnVis.setBounds(250, 250, 150, 50);
        btnVis.setFont(f);
        btnVis.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(btnVis);

        btnQuit = new JButton("Quit");
        btnQuit.setBounds(440,380,100,50);
        btnQuit.setFont(f);
        btnQuit.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(btnQuit);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String Mess = "Hello from the program";
        if (e.getSource() == btnObtainMess)
            lblMessage.setText(Mess);
        if (e.getSource() == btnVis)
            lblMessage.setForeground(Color.RED);
        if (e.getSource() == btnNotVis)
            lblMessage.setForeground(lblMessage.getBackground());
        if (e.getSource() == btnQuit)   
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run 'incremental.class' but your class is actually with a capital I: Incremental. Java classes are case-sensetive.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for  offtop, but this will help you to run your application correctly:

```
this.setVisible(true); ->

final Incremental self = this;
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        self.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

This will allow for your ui event listeners to be independent from main thread.

And  [nbokmans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3061857/nbokmans) is right - looks like you run from console like

`"java ... incrimental.java"` instead of `Incremental`

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me in eclipse using run as -> java application.

If you are trying to run it from command line you must use this command to compile:

```
javac pkIncremental/Incremental.java
```

And then this one to run:

```
java pkIncremental.Incremental
```